# Flask application downloads archive instead of Excel files

Tags: excel, flask, pandas.excelwriter

I am reusing some code posted here [Excel export with Flask server and xlsxwriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426879/excel-export-with-flask-server-and-xlsxwriter):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO
from flask import Flask, send_file

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')

def index():

    #create a random Pandas dataframe
    df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

    #create an output stream
    output = BytesIO()
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')

    #taken from the original question
    df_1.to_excel(writer, startrow = 0, merge_cells = False, sheet_name = "Sheet_1")
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets["Sheet_1"]
    format = workbook.add_format()
    format.set_bg_color('#eeeeee')
    worksheet.set_column(0,9,28)

    #the writer has done its job
    writer.close()

    #go back to the beginning of the stream
    output.seek(0)

    #finally return the file
    return send_file(output, attachment_filename="testing.xlsx", as_attachment=True)

app.run(debug=True)
```

I am running Ubuntu 18 and my code sits in a docker container. Unfortunately this code doesn't download an xlsx file. It downloads an entire archive, e.g. with subfolders etc. Hence I played with the mimetype in send_file but no success. What could be wrong with my setup. Funny enough I can open the archive directly in LibreOffice Calc and I get the worksheets I was expecting to see.
I have also tried to locally export the BytesIO into an actual file and send this file but no success. Maybe it's a browser problem?

Answer (score 2):

since you want to send `.xlsx` (Microsoft Excel OpenXML) and not `.xls` (Microsoft Excel), i think you have to force the right `mimetype` parameter in `send_file()` like :

```
[..]
#finally return the file
    return send_file(output,
                     attachment_filename="testing.xlsx",
                     mimetype="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", # here
                     as_attachment=True)
```

refer to the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types